# Socket.io lost connection and never reconnect

Tags: socket.io

Once emitted is signal error from socket.io (below dump from that error) connection is lost and never estabilished again, I can provide some additional info if necessary.

```
{
  cancelBubble: false,    
  returnValue: true,
  defaultPrevented: false,
  timestamp: 123112123,
  cancelable: false
  bubbles: false,
  eventPhase: 2,
  type: "error",
  srcElement: {
    binaryType: "blob",
    extensions: "",
    protocol: "",
    bufferedAmount: 0,
    readyState: 2,
    url: "ws://xyz.ab/socket.io/1/websocket/583234.."
  },
  target: { ... }, 
  currentTarget: { ... }
}
```

The question is what could be the reason, that socket emitts "error" signal, and how to investigate fix that. Socket.IO.js build:0.9.8

Comment: In my case I have this problem only with Chrome when trying to connect with websockets (Firefox is working). But after that chrome tries xhr-polling and it is then working as expected.

Comment: Oh, I forget about that issue. The problem in my case was on server side - not sure what was the solution (since it wasn't my part), but indeed xhr-polling was working fine. Since Heroku is working with websockets directly, we have abandoned socket.io ;)